# Android: Starting Web Browser From Code

Tags: android

I am trying to open a web browser with a supplied url, however, after the last line of the following code, I get a null pointer exception.  According to the call stack,  `Actvity.startActvitity(Intent)` is where the exception occurs.  This code is in a custom controller  class for a sub view of the main activity.  Any ideas on how to properly start the web browser via code, ideally from outside the main activity since I would to reuse as much as possible.  or at least point me in the right direction.

```
private void showWebSite() {
            String _url = (String) this.urlview.getText();
            Activity webactivity = new Activity();
            Intent webIntent = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_VIEW );
            webIntent.setData( Uri.parse(_url) );
            webactivity.startActivity( webIntent );
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private void showWebSite() {
        String _url = (String) this.urlview.getText();
        //Activity webactivity = new Activity(); Not required
        Intent webIntent = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_VIEW );
        webIntent.setData( Uri.parse(_url) );
        this.startActivity( webIntent );
}
```

If you want it to be reusable create a static method like this

```
 public static void showWebSite(Activity activity, String url) {

        Intent webIntent = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_VIEW );
        webIntent.setData( Uri.parse(url) );
        activity.startActivity( webIntent );
}

/* Call from your activities like this */

CLASSNAME.showWebSite(this, (String) this.urlview.getText());
```

Answer (score 1):

This won't work: you can't instantiate an Activity the way you have tried (`Activity webactivity = new Activity();` will return a class that isn't properly setup by the Android framework, hence the null pointer exception).

You will have to pass in the original Activity to the function: something like this:

```
private void showWebSite(Activity webactivity) {
            String _url = (String) this.urlview.getText();
            Intent webIntent = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_VIEW );
            webIntent.setData( Uri.parse(_url) );
            webactivity.startActivity( webIntent );
    }
```